# Una preposición "a" sigue el verbo "santificar" cuando el complemento directo no es animado?

Tags: gramática, verbos, preposiciones, complemento-directo

Is the Spanish verb **santificar** followed by the preposition **a** when the object is not animate?

Ej 1:

> El sacerdote pide a Dios que santifique la casa.

o

> El sacerdote pide a Dios que santifique a la casa.

Ej 2:

> Tenemos que pedir a él que santifique el aceite y el resto de comida.

o

> Tenemos que pedir a él que santifique al aceite y al resto de comida.

Answer (score 2):

*[Santificar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XG1hZLR)* is a transitive verb with a completely regular behavior, so it follows the same rules as others of its kind: when the direct object is a person or animated entity or a definite group of people (or a person-like or personalizad entity, etc.), it's preceded by *a*; otherwise it isn't. (The *DPD* lays out these [rules for the use of *a*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=a) in detail.)

The most common use of *santificar* without *a* is probably the Third Commandment:

> *Santificar las fiestas.*

In any case the verb is not used in its active form with animate objects very often; one finds it mostly in the passive:

> *Juan el Bautista fue santificado.*